# Are soaked pulses edible without cooking?

Tags: soaking, pulses

I soaked some horse gram overnight in plenty of water and forgot about it in the morning. In the afternoon, I remembered about it and noticed that they were soft enough to be eaten directly without any cooking. They were still under water and hadn't germinated. (I added some salt and ate them and it was good).

Would it be safe/okay to do this regularly, or is cooking pulses necessary if one has the luxury of time to soak them?

Comment: I searched quickly on the internet and got the impression there are two simlar plants. One is *Macrotyloma uniflorum* and the other is *Vicia faba*. The latter is toxic when uncooked.

Comment: Thanks. It did look like the picture in Wikipedia for the first one (Macrotyloma uniflorum)

Comment: That feels like an answer, Bernhard, maybe put it there so that this question clearly has an answer?